# Upload Media to WordPress using REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

how to upload media-image or featured-image in wordpress using rest api.

I've created new post using WordPress REST API, and now I am uploading Image to my Wordpress Site using REST API but i am unable to achieve it due to error "No data Supplied" kindly please Check Screenshot

[image]

which is the best way to create new post in WordPress with Featured Image, right now in my mind

1. Upload Media File to WordPress Site and Get Media ID
2. Create New Post with Media ID

Comment: I dont see images so I added a complete code in answer

Answer (score 6):

you almost right, just lack `media(image) raw binary data`.

for `python`, using code:

```py
import requests

toUploadImagePath = "/xxx/xxx.jpg"
mediaImageBytes = open(toUploadImagePath, 'rb').read()
# b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\.....'

uploadImageFilename = "661b943654f54bd4b2711264eb275e1b.jpg"
curHeaders = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz-xxx-yyy-zzz",
  "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=%s" % uploadImageFilename,
}

resp = requests.post(
  "https://www.crifan.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
  headers=curHeaders,
  data=mediaBytes,
)
```

full code can refer my lib: [crifanWordpress.py](https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/thirdParty/crifanWordpress.py)

and my **Chinese** post: [【已解决】用Python通过WordPress的REST API上传图片](https://www.crifan.com/use_python_upload_image_file_for_wordpress_rest_api)
(will publish in short future)

Answer (score 5):

Using the REST API to upload a file to WordPress is quite simple. All you need is to send the file in a POST-Request to the wp/v2/media route.

**UPDATED** added data response true

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'test.jpg' );
$url = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/';
$ch = curl_init();
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="example.jpg"',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),
] );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
```

MORE https://gist.github.com/ahmadawais/0ccb8a32ea795ffac4adfae84797c19a

Comment: How can we create a post with media in it ? provided media url from extenal source

Comment: @Srinivas08 there's no API option to send url. but you can do by creating custom endpoint to upload media using media_sideload function

Answer (score 0):

I landed here looking for answers too. But I finally mixed and matched PHP and Nodejs. @user1805543's answer was my php code (thanks man). I returned the id from $result. (remember to `json_decode($result, true)`) All that was left to do was to make a get request to that where that php was running - `localhost:YOUR_PORT`

I used axios in my case, so inside the callback I received the id, and I proceeded to make post request for new blog post, supplying the id as featured_media